# Remove AutoCompleteTextView left padding

Tags: android

I would like to remove AutoCompleteTextView's left padding, so I set padding to 0 in my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/auto"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"/>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/auto"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/hello_text_view"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But the result is ugly, I want the underline to start at the beginning of the EditText

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you set android:paddingStart="4dp" instead of 0dp it will look much better
[image]

Comment: I need it to be 0dp